# Extract data from DTO into a custom type

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am learning NestJS and I encountered a problem but it's regarding TypeScript. When using DTOs for mapping from the body of controller I want to extract only some fields of the body, let's say I don't want the confirmPassword field or after creating an user to return some values excluding password, createdAt etc. I created a type with only username and password but I get the following error: `Argument of type 'CreateUserParams' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateUserDTO'. Property 'confirmPassword' is missing in type 'CreateUserParams' but required in type 'CreateUserDTO'.`

In the following code I also use TypeORM and MySQL

This is how the DTO and custom type look like:

```
CreateUser.dto.ts
export class CreateUserDTO {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  confirmPassword: string;
}
```

```
types.ts
export type CreateUserParams = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};
```

and my controller and service function:

```
users.controller.ts
@Post()
  createUser(@Body() createUserDTO: CreateUserDTO) {
    const userDetails: CreateUserParams = {
      username: createUserDTO.username,
      password: createUserDTO.password,
    };
    this.usersService.createUser(userDetails);
  }
```

```
users.service.ts
createUser(userDetails: CreateUserParams) {
    const newUser = this.userRepository.create({
      ...userDetails,
      createdAt: new Date(),
    });

    return this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
```

I can fix this by making the confirmPassword in the DTO optional `confirmPassword?: string` but I want to know another way to extracting the data from the DTO without doing fields optional cause I think there will be situation when I don't want fields optional. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: It seems that you're getting this error somewhere else. The error says you have passed `CreateUserParams` where `CreateUserDTO` was expected, but I don't see a clear example of this in the code you provided. Can you check which function is throwing the error?

Comment: Ok, this is actually kinda embarassing. I looked again at the code today and made `confirmPassword` not optional in the `CreateUser.dto.ts` and there was no error coming from `users.controller.ts`. I have no clue why yesterday it happened and today everything seems to work.  I will play around and see if I encounter the error again.